# maya what is the equivalent of the mel commands getenv and putenv in python?

Tags: python, maya, mel

In Maya, how can I use Python to achieve the same functionality as the MEL commands `getenv` and `putenv`? i've tried to  import maya.mel but it doesn't have a getenv or putenv argument:
`import maya.mel as mel mel.getenv('ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH')`
ie returns

## Error: AttributeError: file  line 2: module 'maya.mel' has no attribute 'getenv'

Comment: Is it simply about `os.getenv('SOME_NAME')` and `os.environ['SOME_NAME'] = 'some_value'`, read and set environmental variables? (`import os`, it's a standard library module)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using the maya.mel.eval command:

## userSetup.py

import maya.mel as mel

X3_PATH="G:/Mon Drive/EDDY ALL WORK/3.0/Eddy3ree/Eddy3ree_01"

path=mel.eval('getenv ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH')+';'+X3_PATH # get path

mel.eval(('putenv ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH \"'+path+'\"'))   # set path

print(mel.eval('getenv ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH'))           # print path